# Storing string into json object python

Tags: python, json

I've read a lot of question regarding this but couldn't find any with str.

I got a long str consisting 16 bytes of name followed by 4 bytes of number and repeated for N number of people. Example as below :

*edit : 1)string is msg

2)added mike into intended output

```
msg = 'George\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0' + '0095' + 'Mikeeeeeeeeeeee\0' + '0100' + 'Kelly\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0' + '0000'
```

And now I need to store these data into json object. I've tried loop but it always rewrites the stored data before. I want something that works as below but for a lot longer string since writing msg[start:end] for every data is completely retarded.

```
data = {}
data[msg[0:16]] = {
    "marks" : msg[16:20]
}
data[msg[20:36]] = {
    "marks" : msg[36:40]
}
data[msg[40:56]] = {
    "marks" : msg[56:60]
}
```

intended output:

```
{
"George\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000": {
    "marks": "0095"
    }, 
"Kelly\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000": {
    "marks": "0000"
    },
 "Mikeeeeeeeeeeee\u0000": {
    "marks": "0100"
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: thats because you are making objects of every part of string instead of making it the intended nested object

Comment: you've posted `string` variable comprised of some chunks of text and then you are working with `msg` variable. Show the `msg` value

Comment: and what about `Mikee` in the msg string you have ?

Comment: I've edited the question. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want all of the object details i.e. George, mike and kelly in your `data` and you msg is of length 60 only while you are accessing 76 and onwards.. therefore to start appending you objects. You should make a nested json according to what you what you want as output result like:

```
length = len(msg)
i = 0
data = {}
while i < length:
    data[msg[i:i+16]] = {"marks" : msg[i+16:i+20]}
    i += 20
print data
```

Output :

```
{'George\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00': {'marks': '0095'}, 'Mikeeeeeeeeeeee\x00': {'marks': '0100'}, 'Kelly\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00': {'marks': '0000'}}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `msg` is sent by server hence I would never have the actual length of data.
I'm hoping to get rid of the number in msg[start:end]

Comment: ok so you want dynamic creation of data object ? and is this the way you want your output to be? will the msg string length will always be in multiple of 20 since your complete parsing is based on that

Comment: yes. something that would ease the object creation without using 'magic number'

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
dict(re.findall(r'(\D+)(\d{4})', string))
```

It will return response like..

```
{'George\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00': '0095', 'Kelly\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00': '0000', 'Mikeeeeeeeeeeee\x00': '0100'}
```

As you got this as dict now, This can be changed in whatever format you want.